# Convert URL GET var to another variable

Tags: php, get

I have a URL variable that looks like this:

```
http://myURL?price_rang=2%5E%5E99_5%5E%5E99
```

With php echo on the price_rang GET var it translates to 25E5E99_55E5E99 .

I need it to be converted to 2.99_5.99 and then explode it and use the first and second part in a query.

What would be the best way to convert this string and explode it (or just convert it)?

Comment: "best" is quite subjective here...have you tried a regex? Strip the all "E" chars and then split it on the underscore...use an online regex tester to get it right: https://regex101.com/r/aH4uO3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it step by step.

1. get the info
2. replace your string
3. explode

Try the following:

```
$range = $_GET['price_rang'];
$range = str_replace("^^", ".", $range);
$val = explode("_", $range);
var_dump($val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need rawurldecode() or urldecode() function

```
$val = explode('_', rawurldecode($_GET['price_rang']));
```

Comment: I believe that rawurldecode will probably produce 2^^99_5^^99?

Comment: And? After urldecode you can fix it for example with str_replace.

Comment: So why even use urldecode if I can just fix it straight away with str_replace on the 5E? :)

Comment: Because (raw)urldecode function is tested of PHP developers, and your dirty code -- no :)